# What is the difference between val?.toLocaleString() and using an if statement to check undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, undefined

I have this:

```
return '£' + val?.toLocaleString();
```

to check if val has a value, however I'm not sure how safe this is compared to the following:

```
if(val) {
    return '£' + val.toLocaleString();
}
return val
```

Could someone help me breakdown what the differences are here and why one is preferable, if that is the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First one if the `val` is `undefined` or `null` it will concate the value of `val` with `undefined`

```js
function format(val) {
  return '£' + val?.toLocaleString();
}

console.log(format())
console.log(format(null))
console.log(format(3))
```

The second one will only make concatenation if `val` is a truthy value, else will return `val` as it's

**Just keep in mind that zero is a falsy value.**

```js
function format(val) {
  if(val) {
    return '£' + val.toLocaleString();
  }
  return val
}

console.log(format())
console.log(format(0))
console.log(format(3))
```